# How to swap rows or columns in a two dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, multidimensional-array

Below code prints out a two dimensional array , with a user desired no. of rows and columns .The problem is that I want to change the position of every row in the matrix .

> Lets suppose my input is `5` and `5` then it will print a 2-D array of
>   1 1 1 1 1
>   2 2 2 2 2
>   3 3 3 3 3
>   4 4 4 4 4
>   5 5 5 5 5
>   And I want this `array` to change into
>   5 5 5 5 5
>   4 4 4 4 4
>   3 3 3 3 3
>   2 2 2 2 2
>   1 1 1 1 1
>   $Code$

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n, m;
cout << "Enter the number of rows n = "; cin >> n;
cout << "Enter the number of columns m = "; cin >> m;

int **array = new int *[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   array[i] = new int [m];

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));   

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
       array[i][j] = i;
       cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    } 
    cout << '\n';
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Come up with a strategy. You want to swap elements in row `i` with those in row `n-1-i`.

Comment: Do you actually want to swap the lines or merely print them backwards?

Comment: Swaping and printing seems to be the same thing . Because the result is one .But I think swaping would be a better option . If yes then how can I access the rows ,to swap them ?

Comment: No they're not. Swapping is a bit more work than just printing in reverse order.

Comment: I meant in case of the answer in the above code

Comment: I already gave the clue for accessing index for swapping. For just printing reverse order, you run your existing outer loop from largest `n` to smallest.

Comment: @ lurker , Okay, can you just show me how to access the rows in order to reverse their order

Comment: Do you know which index in `array[i][j]` is the column and which is the row?

Comment: `[i]` is the row

Answer (score 0):

Here do this

```
For(i=0,j=4;i<5;i++,j--)
{
      For(k=0;k<5;k++)
      {
            Arr2[j][k]=arr1[i][k];
      }
}
```